# Enterprise Architect set positions of elements and associated complex types

Tags: xsd, schema, enterprise-architect

I have to determine the position of XML elements in a sequence model group. I use the "position" tagged value (starting from 1) to achieve that. It works, if the XSDcomplexType only contains elements with the XSDelement stereotype or if it has only associations to other XSDcomplexTyp classes (with the tagged value "position" on the "Connector Source").

If I try to sort the sequence of complex types, which have XSDelements and associations to other XSDcomplexTyp classes, the defined sequence will be ignored. I noticed that in this case, the associated elements will be added at first.

I use the Enterprise Architect in version 15.1.1526.

Is there any way to fix the order of the elements defined in the XSDcomplexType and the elements, which will be generated by the association, to other XSDcomplexType classes?

Comment: When I once used to model XSD I had my own importer since EA's build-in was not really useable since not configurable in any way. I don't think there's anything you can do except wriing a feature request (whch is hopeless). Or doing like I did in the past. Or maybe Geert has an idea.

Comment: Using the position tags in the attributes and connector source should work. I'm pretty sure it worked when I tested this a while ago. I would first try with the latest version, and if you still have a problem send in a bug report.